# Possible to send/recieve PHP data from changing an option in a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsonp

Let's say I have a select box like this:

```
<select style="margin-top: 5px; width: 190px;" id="daySelect">
    <option>Monday, April 1st</option>
    <option>Tuesday, April 2nd</option>
    <option>Wednesday, April 3rd</option>
    <option>Thursday, April 4th</option>
    <option>Friday, April 5th</option>
    <option>Saturday, April 6th</option>
    <option>Sunday, April 7th</option>
    <option>Monday, April 8th</option>
</select>
```

I want to send some variables to php to write to a file and right after load information fom the selected dropdown (The information I'm saving/loading will be in JSON if that matters).

For example: If I'm currently on Monday, April 1st and i have a variable xyz in JSON. When I click on Tuesday, April 2nd, I want to save xyz to the server (with php) and find Tuesday's xyz variable and load it.

I'm just wondering if this possible? And any ideas on how to approach the code on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the code to write to the file will be in a standard php script.  You will need to use javascript to attach an onchange handler to the select box which will fire an ajax request sending data to the php page.  The php page can then echo out some data which will be returned in the success handler of the ajax request allowing you to handle the returned data on the front end.

I would suggest looking into jQuery as it makes life a lot simpler.

Comment: If you decide to use jQuery for this, you might want to look at http://zeptojs.com/ or similar "lighter" libraries that are jQuery-like. No need to throw a tank of a solution at a feather of a problem.

Comment: Very true, I tend to use jQuery mainly because I use a lot of the other functionality and to be honest am most familiar with it.

Comment: Yeah I know how it goes, if you're already using it you also tend to find pretty good use for more and more of it's features as well. It's the gift that keeps on giving!

Comment: Ok cool, I've already included the JQuery library for other things, so that works. Do you know what the syntax is for AJAX jquery request (in the past, I've only received data with AJAX) never sent it.

Comment: If you take a look at the jQuery documentation it details very clearly how to do it with lots of examples :) and to be honest you will learn a lot more trying it yourself by looking at the docs than you would if we explain it on here. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  you may also want to look into the post varient if this suits your needs better or one of the other varients like getJson

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon's point, but here's the gist of it anyway :)

```
$('#daySelect').on('change', function() {
  $.get({
    uri: '/your/php/script',
    data: $(this).val(),
    success: function() { console.log('success') },
    error: function() { console.log('something went wrong') }
  });
});
```